# How to mimic cv2.Sobel using np.gradient?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, gradient

I want to get the image in the x-axis and y-axis differential directions. But, I want to code using `np.gradient` function, without using `cv2.Sobel` filter.

So, I want to convert code like this

```py
x_grad = cv2.Sobel(image1, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)
```

to something like this

```py
x_grad = np.gradient(image1, axis=0)
```

But, the values ​​are not the same. How should I fix it?

Comment: The [Sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) is not a simple finite difference gradient, so there's no reason they should be the same

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but let me understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) has limited functionality, and only a few cases of [`cv2.Sobel`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d) can be somehow reproduced, namely the following:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

grad_cv2 = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=1)
grad_np = 2 * np.gradient(image, axis=1)
grad_np[:, [0, -1]] = 0
print(np.all(grad_cv2 == grad_np))
# True

grad_cv2 = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=1)
grad_np = 2 * np.gradient(image, axis=0)
grad_np[[0, -1], :] = 0
print(np.all(grad_cv2 == grad_np))
# True

grad_cv2 = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 1, ksize=3)
grad_np = 2 * np.gradient(2 * np.gradient(image, axis=1), axis=0)
grad_np[:, [0, -1]] = 0
grad_np[[0, -1], :] = 0
print(np.all(grad_cv2 == grad_np))
# True
```

Factor `2` is needed, since `np.gradient` divides by `2` per default.

Setting the border(s) to zero must be done, because of the following (emphasis by me):

> The gradient is computed using second order accurate central differences in the interior points and either first or second order accurate **one-sides** (forward or backwards) **differences at the boundaries**.

On the other hand, `cv2.Sobel`, per default, uses `cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101`, such that you always get `0` for the borders.

Most other cases of `cv2.Sobel` will involve (Gaussian) smoothing, cf. the linked documentation:

> The Sobel operators combine Gaussian smoothing and differentiation, so the result is more or less resistant to the noise.

That can't be attacked solely using `np.gradient`. If you want to have that, you're going to rewrite `cv2.Sobel` using NumPy methods.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: OpenCV documentation is known to have a lot of BS in it. Right after the sentence you quote they show the kernels, which smooth with a [1,2,1] kernel along one dimension and compute derivative with [1,0,-1] along the other. This is the original definition of the Sobel filter. [1,2,1] is a triangular filter, it doesn’t look like a Gaussian at all, and has very different properties from a Gaussian (check its response in the Fourier domain to understand the important differences).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Definitely not going to question your expertise on image processing fundamentals - or defending OpenCV devs/docs, here. As you noticed, I just referenced their doc. If you're sure about their implementation, maybe by verifying, that their generated Sobel kernels are the "common" ones, maybe suggest an corresponding edit on their doc or open an issue on their bug tracker!? That way, everybody would profit and possible errors/inaccuracies don't lead to misunderstandings in the future.

Comment: I don’t know, fixing the OpenCV docs is an uphill battle. There are misunderstandings and inaccuracies on just about every page.